# How to run a program on build/release failure?

Tags: tfs, build, devops

I need to run a console app on build/release failure.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the steps describe below to achieve the running of console app with the failure of the build.

1. Checked in a simple solution with console app just printing "Console app has run!" to allow the build to build and make console app available. Instead you can directly check in the console app and make it copy to the build/release agent

   Console.WriteLine("Console app has run!");
2. In the build definition to simulate fail build added below PowerShell task inline

   Write-Host "Hello World"

   Write-Error ("Some error")

   exit 1

[image]

3. Then added run command line task providing path to console application. The control option is set to execute this task only when a previous task has failed.

[image]

**When the PowerShell task is failing and build is failing**, the publish task just after that, does not execute, but the console app running task is **executed** since it is set to execute when a previous task fails.

[image]

**When the PowerShell task not failing** (removed error creating steps from PS script) **and build is not failing**, console application running task is **not executed**.

[image]

Comment: My, that was easy! I was expecting it to be much more complex. And to think... the configuration setting was staring right at me all along. Chaminda: it appears this solution can also work for the release that's triggered by this same build—would you agree?

Comment: @InteXX it would work with release if a release task failed and if you want to execute a console app on a release task failure. But if the build fails there will be no release triggered.

Comment: Right, I understand that. What I'm setting up is a way to cancel a new build if the build/release pipeline is still active. In this particular case, a successful deployment depends on the prior release (I'm using Squirrel, and it uses the latest published version to generate a delta update). So if I accidentally kick off a build while either the build or release is still active, I need to fail the premature build that I just started. The next trick is to get the necessary id info from the build to the release in order to link the two, but that should be pretty easy.

Comment: This is a great answer, chock full of excellent detail. You put some time into this one; I appreciate it.

Comment: I'm curious—what did you use to get your yellow highlight circles?

Comment: @InteXX it is Snagit Editor